# Adding GET variable To existing GET variable in URL

Tags: php

I am trying to add a get variable to the content of the url, here is my url

```
example.com/all_members.php?limit=3&page_no=2
```

I am try to add more get variable to the url using a search form with method GET,but after clicking search, the url turns to

```
example.com/all_members.php?search_by=email&name=email@adress.com
```

I am trying to get a url like

```
example.com/all_members.php?limit=3&page_no=2&search_by=email&name=email@adress.com
```

Here is the form

```
    <form method="GET" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="search_by" required>
            <option></option>
            <option style="font-weight:bold;">name</option>
            <option style="font-weight:bold;">email</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Search
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: why is the directory pointing to  "projects"  ?

Comment: you need to show your `form` with `search` button

Comment: Make sure that your existing variables are all in the form using `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: I just added the form code

Comment: @ben I have fixed that

Comment: so did you get the solution @Muhammed

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal variant but it's working )) You can use hidden input

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : "" ?>" name="limit">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= isset($_GET['page_no']) ? $_GET['page_no'] : "" ?>" name="page_no">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I modified your code to

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="hidden" value="<? if(isset($_GET['limit']){ echo $_GET['limit'];} ?>" name="limit">
<input type="hidden" value="<? if(isset($_GET['page_no'])){ echo $_GET['page_no'];} ?>" name="page_no">
<input type="submit">
```